# getting proto sources from http_archive in bazel

Tags: protocol-buffers, bazel

I'm new to bazel. I am trying out migrating some parts of my company's vast build to bazel. We have some protos zipped up in nexus. I need to grab several archives and compile all the contained proto files together. I have tried all sorts and just can't get it to work.

I'm using an `http_archive` with a `filegroup` to get the files.

```
http_archive(
    name = "protos_1",
    url = "..."
    build_file_content = """
filegroup(
    name = "files",
    srcs = glob(["**/*.proto"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"]
)
""",
)
```

Now I figured I would just do something like:

```
proto_library(
    name = "combined_protos",
    srcs = [
        "@protos_1//:files",
        "@protos_2//:files",
    ],
)
```

but no dice. I've tried using the filegroups as `deps` and `data` and everything else I can think of. Any tips?

thanks.

Comment: What errors are you seeing, exactly?

Comment: @Jin when i use the proto_library as shown abouve i get 

`ERROR: /path/to/build/BUILD:3:12: in srcs attribute of proto_library rule //somebuild:proto: Proto source with label '@protos_1//:files' must be in same package as consuming rule.`

i can't define the proto_library in the `protos_1` BUILD file because the protos contain imports from `protos_2` and so on.